# cl.exe /c - Command line warning D9002

Tags: windows, command-line, compilation, linker, cl

I'm trying to use Microsoft's compiler (`cl`) from the command line to produce unlinked object files:

```
cl /c /nologo /OUT:main.obj main.c
```

`main.c` is an empty `main` function:

```
int main( void ) { return 0; }
```

The object file is generated, but `cl` outputs a few `D9002` warnings:

```
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/OU'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/OT'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O:'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Om'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Oa'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/On'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/O.'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Oo'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Ob'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Oj'
```

As I understand, these are linker options that are automatically passed to `cl`, since it's also used for linking.

However in my case, as I don't invoke the linker (by specifying `/C`), it seems that `cl` gets confused by these unexpected default options.

Is there a way to override these default options, or to suppress the output of these warnings?

Comment: `cl` parses `/OUT:main.obj` as `/OU /OT /O: /Om ...` which are invalid. Note that there is no warning raised for [/Oi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/oi-generate-intrinsic-functions?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Wow... How did I miss that! Thanks 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/OUT` is not a compiler option. If you want to compile without linking, use the following command line:

```
cl /c /nologo main.c
```

The name of the object file is implied by the source file name. The previous compiler invocation outputs main.obj.